# How to put the figures and tables in the right places using knitr, rstudio and Sweave to generate a pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr

I am trying to use knitr and RStudio to generate a pdf. My question is: I cannot put the figures and tables in the right places. Please take a look at this simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{\textbf{\large{Reports: }}}
\author{\large{***}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

<<echo= F,message = F,warning = F>>=
# Set the global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(echo = F, # Do NOT repeat code in final document
               message = F, # Do NOT print R messages in document
               warning = F # Do NOT print warnings
               )
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(xtable)
library(stringr)
@

\section*{\large{Overview}}  %with *, then no number
<<>>=
myWhole <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(2,3,4,5))
@
\begin{figure}
<<echo = F, fig.width = 4, fig.height = 1.5, fig.align = 'center'>>=
ggplot(myWhole,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point()
@
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-1pt}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{****}
\end{figure}
\section*{\large{Query 6: ***}}
just try...just try...just try...just try...just try...just try...just     try...just try...
\begin{table}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-10pt}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{}
<<echo=FALSE,results='asis',message=FALSE>>=
xt=xtable(myWhole)
print(xt,tabular.environment="longtable",floating=F)
@
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You can see the figure belongs to the first section and the table belongs to the second. I hope the order should be:

```
section title: Overview
words
figure
words
section title: query 6
words
table
words
```

But the generated PDF looks like this:

[image]

Even this picture is not clear, you can still see that they are not in the right places. And the table is on the second page although there is plenty room on the first page. Could anyone please help me here?

Comment: This is more of a LaTeX question than anything to do with any of your tags.  The simple answer is:  don't put your figure and table in floats if you don't want it to float where LaTeX chooses.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat for more details

Comment: Thanks, I found this solution too.